# C++ get variable from PHP?

Tags: php, c++

I have create a web interface, which allow user to choose a txt file. My C++ program will go to the folder and execute based on txt file choose by user ( Basically the text file content is about configuration, so the program need load the configuration based on user choose at webpage ). Now the problem is, how can I pass the text file name to cpp program. The coding I attach with bold and Italic is won't work, just the intention I want to archieve.

```
int main(***string filename***)
{
using namespace std;
vector<string> strings;

string path = "/home/pi/Desktop/DMixer_Webinterface_Downloadfile/";
string fullpath = path + ***filename***;

//  ifstream file("/home/pi/Desktop/DMixer_Webinterface_Downloadfile/abc_2017_03_10_23_24_52.txt");
ifstream file(fullpath);
std::string str;

while (std::getline(file, str, ','))
{
    myArray[array_count] = str; // store those value in array
                                //  cout << str << "\n";
    strings.push_back(str);
    array_count++;
}
x_gap_value = atof(myArray[2].c_str());
y_gap_value = atof(myArray[3].c_str());
return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you want to learn how to handle command-line arguments in a C++ program? There are thousands of examples and tutorials about the issue, as well as it being described in many books.

Comment: Is it I pass an argument outside ( from PHP ) to the command-line of C++ then it will work?

Answer (score 0):

Just put

```
string param
```

in your main method, and call your program with an argument with a param.

Tut:

http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DEN36Up4/